# How do I compare values in two dataframe in an efficient way

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWseB.png)
[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHo0t.png)

I am new with python, pandas and Stack Overflow, so I will appreciate any help. I have two panda dataframes, the first one is in ascending order(values from 0 to 100 in steps of 0.1), the second one has 26000 values from 2.3 to 38.5, in no order, some values are also repeated in that dataframe. What I am trying to do is, for each value in the first dataframe, find how many values in the second dataframe are less than or equal to that value in an efficient way.

My code below does it in 45 seconds, but I'd like it to be done in around 10.

Thanks in advance:

Code:

```
def get_CDF2(df1, df2): 
    x=df1 #The first dataframe is already sorted in ascending order
    y = np.sort(df2, axis=0) #Sort the columns of the second dataframe in ascending order
    df_res = []  # keep the results here
    yi = iter(y)  # Use of an iterator to move over y
    yindex = 0
    flag = 0 #Flag, when set to 1 no comparison is done
    y_val = next(yi)
    for value in x:

        if flag >=1:
            df_res.append(largest_ind)#append the number of y_val smaller than value
            #yindex+1
        else:
            # Search through y to find the index of an item bigger than value
            while (y_val) <= (value) and yindex < len(y)-1:
                y_val= next(yi) #Point at the next value in df2
                yindex += 1 #Keep track of how many y_val are smaller than value
            '''if for any value in df1 we iterate through the entire df2 and they are all less, that means
            the rest of values in df1 will have the same effect since df1 is in ascending other, so no need to iterate again,
            just set flag to 1'''
            if ((yindex==len(y)-1)) and ((y_val <= float(value))): 
                flag=1
                largest_ind=yindex+1
                df_res.append(largest_ind)#append the number of y_val smaller than value
            else:
                df_res.append(yindex) #append the number of y_val smaller than value

    return df_res
```

df1:

```
     0. ,   0.1,   0.2,   0.3,   0.4,   0.5,   0.6,   0.7,   0.8,
     0.9,   1. ,   1.1,   1.2,   1.3,   1.4,   1.5,   1.6,   1.7,
     1.8,   1.9,   2. ,   2.1,   2.2,   2.3,   2.4,   2.5,   2.6,
     2.7,   2.8,   2.9,   3. ,   3.1,   3.2,   3.3,   3.4,   3.5,
     3.6,   3.7,   3.8,   3.9,   4. ,   4.1,   4.2,   4.3,   4.4,
     4.5,   4.6,   4.7,   4.8,   4.9,   5. ,   5.1,   5.2,   5.3,
     5.4,   5.5,   5.6,   5.7,   5.8,   5.9,   6. ,   6.1,   6.2,
     6.3,   6.4,   6.5,   6.6,   6.7,   6.8,   6.9,   7. ,   7.1,
     7.2,   7.3,   7.4,   7.5,   7.6,   7.7,   7.8,   7.9,   8. ,
     8.1,   8.2,   8.3,   8.4,   8.5,   8.6,   8.7,   8.8,   8.9,
     9. ,   9.1,   9.2,   9.3,   9.4,   9.5,   9.6,   9.7,   9.8,
     9.9,  10. ,  10.1,  10.2,  10.3,  10.4,  10.5,  10.6,  10.7,
    10.8,  10.9,  11. ,  11.1,  11.2,  11.3,  11.4,  11.5,  11.6,
    11.7,  11.8,  11.9,  12. ,  12.1,  12.2,  12.3,  12.4,  12.5,
    12.6,  12.7,  12.8,  12.9,  13. ,  13.1,  13.2,  13.3,  13.4,
    13.5,  13.6,  13.7,  13.8,  13.9,  14. ,  14.1,  14.2,  14.3,
    14.4,  14.5,  14.6,  14.7,  14.8,  14.9,  15. ,  15.1,  15.2,
    15.3,  15.4,  15.5,  15.6,  15.7,  15.8,  15.9,  16. ,  16.1,
    16.2,  16.3,  16.4,  16.5,  16.6,  16.7,  16.8,  16.9,  17. ,
    17.1,  17.2,  17.3,  17.4,  17.5,  17.6,  17.7,  17.8,  17.9,
    18. ,  18.1,  18.2,  18.3,  18.4,  18.5,  18.6,  18.7,  18.8,
    18.9,  19. ,  19.1,  19.2,  19.3,  19.4,  19.5,  19.6,  19.7,
    19.8,  19.9,  20. ,  20.1,  20.2,  20.3,  20.4,  20.5,  20.6,
    20.7,  20.8,  20.9,  21. ,  21.1,  21.2,  21.3,  21.4,  21.5,
    21.6,  21.7,  21.8,  21.9,  22. ,  22.1,  22.2,  22.3,  22.4,
    22.5,  22.6,  22.7,  22.8,  22.9,  23. ,  23.1,  23.2,  23.3,
    23.4,  23.5,  23.6,  23.7,  23.8,  23.9,  24. ,  24.1,  24.2,
    24.3,  24.4,  24.5,  24.6,  24.7,  24.8,  24.9,  25. ,  25.1,
    25.2,  25.3,  25.4,  25.5,  25.6,  25.7,  25.8,  25.9,  26. ,
    26.1,  26.2,  26.3,  26.4,  26.5,  26.6,  26.7,  26.8,  26.9,
    27. ,  27.1,  27.2,  27.3,  27.4,  27.5,  27.6,  27.7,  27.8,
    27.9,  28. ,  28.1,  28.2,  28.3,  28.4,  28.5,  28.6,  28.7,
    28.8,  28.9,  29. ,  29.1,  29.2,  29.3,  29.4,  29.5,  29.6
```

df2:

```
0         12.993
1         12.054
2         21.957
3         10.917
4         33.890
5         10.597
6         22.911
7          7.431
8         10.437
9         19.165
10        12.169
11        14.847
12        10.093
13        10.795
14        14.419
15        27.199
16        15.045
17        12.764
18         7.766
19        18.066
20        10.254
21        16.922
22         7.011
23        10.322
24        11.619
25        25.719
26        18.142
27        14.557
28        26.367
29        13.443
30        17.318
31        10.971
32         6.073
33        20.050
34        11.863
35        25.619
36        18.326
37        30.830
38        13.130
39        11.734
40        14.457
41        22.659
42        16.479
43        17.845
44        23.712
45        16.670
46        10.322
47        16.250
48        20.920
49        17.479
50        15.526
51        15.732
52        19.836
53        10.513
54        24.818
55        10.933
56        14.785
57        25.253
58        15.732
59        14.290
60        23.979
61        24.788
62        12.420
63        21.324
64         9.658
65        24.307
66        17.601
67        12.352
68        18.089
69        23.353
70        12.718
71        18.707
72         9.147
73        17.494
74         8.743
75        22.407
76        16.227
77        15.396
78        16.807
79        26.733
80        14.084
81        19.516
82        15.106
83        21.187
84        13.008
85        13.618
86        16.266
87        19.706
88         6.591
89        14.999
90        16.449
91        18.883
92        15.243
93        15.976
94        18.242
95        16.662
96         6.691
97        16.952
98        25.940
99        23.018
100       29.365
101       14.564
102       15.625
103        9.727
104        7.652
105       12.726
106        7.263
107       19.943
108       17.540
109        7.469
110       10.360
111       17.898
112       20.393
113        7.011
114       15.999
115       12.985
116       16.624
117       18.753
118       12.520
119       13.488
120       17.959
121       16.433
122       14.518
123       12.909
124       19.752
125        9.277
126       25.566
127       19.272
128       10.360
129       22.148
130       20.294
131       18.402
132       17.631
133       17.341
134       13.672
135       19.600
136       20.653
137       15.999
138       15.480
139       30.655
140       15.426
141       16.067
142       29.838
143       13.099
144       12.184
145       15.693
146       26.031
147       16.052
148        8.087
149       16.754
150       17.029
151       16.601
152        9.956
153       20.363
154       11.215
155       15.106
156       13.809
157       23.178
158       21.484
159       13.359
160       31.860
161       14.564
162       19.737
163       19.424
164       29.556
165       15.678
166       22.148
167       28.389
168       21.309
169       22.262
170       11.314
171        8.018
172       24.551
173       14.740
174       15.716
175       24.269
176       20.042
177       15.968
178       11.337
179       27.618
180       22.522
181       19.066
182        9.323
183       20.622
184       13.092
185       15.464
186       21.171
187       11.604
188       19.050
189       15.823
190       33.859
191       15.106
192       13.549
193       17.296
194       13.740
195       12.054
196       10.955
197       21.164
198       14.427
199        9.719
200       12.176
201        9.742
202       21.278
203       20.515
204       18.265
205        9.666
206       13.870
207       15.968
208       13.313
209       16.517
210       18.417
211       15.419
212       20.523
213       15.655
214       26.977
215       13.084
216       31.349
217       29.854
218       13.008
219       11.306
220       22.384
221       20.798
222       17.433
223       12.916
224       11.284
225       20.248
226        9.803
227       10.376
228        9.315
229       14.976
230       16.327
231        9.590
232       16.830
233       23.979
234       11.558
235       13.183
236       18.776
237       20.416
238        9.163
239       10.345
240       28.252
241       22.888
242       20.538
243        6.912
244       24.040
245        8.682
246       31.929
247       14.908
248       19.195
249       17.112
250       18.379
251       15.869
252       13.794
253       14.129
254       12.458
255       10.795
256       25.291
257       26.382
258       20.881
```

Comment: can you share what your dataframes look like?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis see the updated post

Comment: @JohnE okay, see the edit I just made

Comment: @LeStivi, none of this is reproducible. can you create a small dataframe from scratch which does the operation you want. then ask for ways to optimize.

Comment: @LeStivi  ideally the sample data is smaller than this but this is much better

Comment: I second @jp_data_analysis please share your dataframes  with `df.to_dict()` and, as you're new, have a look at [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will add a column called `check` to `df1`. The column will contain the count of the values in df2 that are <= each value in df1.

```
df1['check'] = df1[0].apply(lambda x: df2[df2[0] <= x].size)
```

You may have to replace the [0] with the names of the first column in your data frames.

Comment: unfortunately both of m y dataframes do not have columns

Comment: That means these are not DataFrames. Please post the code where you create ``df1`` and ``df2``.

Comment: I found a way to add column names, and I tried your answer, but it doesnt give the right answer, and it takes just about the same time as my solution

Comment: Please post the portion of the code where you create the dataframes.